# Journey Builder: Merged contact should not re-enter the journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact

I have created a journey builder to send welcome email based on registration

Criteria : Registration date Stamped in contact record 
            It will send welcome email through JB

Now when in salesforce when two contacts are merged and one of the contact has already entered journey before, now if merge happened and losing contact registration field is carry forwarded to winning contact, Now winning contact will again enter in to the journey because it will have new contact ID. How to avoid this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a checkbox field in salesforce and use this field (Email sent) as one of the filter criteria, i..e, whenever the email is sent to that contact then “Email sent” flag will set to true

Build a journey based on the Registration date and Email sent field (Sales cloud) as filters in contact object ( when Registration date is stamped and Email sent is equal to false then contact will enter the journey)

After Message activity in Journey Builder, select Update contact activity and choose “Email sent” field to update ( that way, whenever email is sent to that contact it will update “Email sent” flag to TRUE)

Note: Every time when contacts are merged make sure to carry forward “Email sent” field  to winning contact